# Reverse migration with South throwing error because table doesn't exist

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-south, psql

I am trying to do a rollback with South in my django app. I am getting this message when I run my command: `DatabaseError: table "forms_logo_version" does not exist`. This is the command I'm running  `python manage.py migrate myformsapp 0044`.

I've checked the DB and the table does not exist, but why is this a problem? If I am deleting the table anyway, why is this throwing an error? Is there anyway I force the script to continue?

I have simply created a blank table in the database and the script ran fine after that. I would still like to know the answer to my questions above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find in your migrations file 0044_*.py method named `backwards` and remove line with something similar to `db.delete_table('forms_logo_version')`. If you do this makes some tests. 
Connect to empty db and make forward migration and backwards, to be sure your changes don't affect another migration file.

I recommend you to figure it out why this table is missing from db? Probably `South` create this table (look into migrations) and only `South` should remove it.